# How to provide custom Authentication in jive forum?

Tags: authentication, forum

I am using jive 5.0 forum. I have my own user tables with user id and password. How can i use this to provide Authentication for jive? The password is encrypted using sha-1 hashing technique.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. it was there are a couple of classes such as CustomAuthFactory CustomAuthToken CustomUser CustomUserManager which are explained in the documentation of Jive forum.